# Isomorphism between the direct sum of submodules and generated submodule

Tags: modules, direct-sum

I am reading Dummit & Foote Chapter 10 and stuck on this exercise ($R$ is a ring with $1$ and $M$ is a left $R$-module):
[image: df10.3.21]

I am unsure about how to proceed in (i) => (ii). I assume the direct sum in (i) means external direct sum (as the problem itself is essentially defining internal direct sum). We are given an isomorphism, but we don't know whether it's the natural one. How can we use this isomorphism to prove (ii)?

Comment: Direct product is the *product* in the category of modules (satisfying universal property for projections and maps *into* it); whereas, the direct sum is the *coproduct* in the category of modules (satisfying universal property for inclusions and maps *out of* it). It happens that in this category for *finite* index sets, the two notions overlap, it's good to keep things straight and not conflate the two dual notions.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typos. I do not intend to refer to direct product in any means.

Comment: How about forming the external direct sum $M':=\bigoplus_{i\in I} N_i$ and map it onto $M$ by $\varphi: M'\rightarrow M$ and $\varphi( (n_i)_{i\in I} := \sum_{i\in I} n_i.$ The latter sum is of course finite, due to the definition of the external direct sum. Then we can identify the "components" $N_i$ of the external direct sum $M'$ with the submodules $N_i$ of $M$. By hypothesis, $M$ is generated by the $N_i$ and hence $\varphi$ is surjective. The injectivity of $\varphi$ is equivalent to condition $(ii)$.

Comment: This is the natural map, but the problem is we don't know it's an isomorphism. We are given an isomorphism, but it might not be the natural map.