# $N_i$'s independent $\iff$ $\oplus_i N_i\cong\sum_i N_i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

**Notation and conventions:** I will use $\oplus$ for the "external direct sums" only. All the modules will be over a commutative ring with unity, $A$.

**Problem:** In the proof of one of the theorems that our professor presented in a lecture, he essentially used the following. Given a module $M$ and a submodule $N$ such that $M\cong N\oplus M$, it was claimed that $N = 0$. But why? Note that it's "$\cong$" and not "$=$". So, I attempted to craft a relevant lemma. This is what I came up with:

> Let $\{N_i\}$ be modules of $M$ such that $\sum_i N_i\cong\oplus_i N_i$. Then $N_i$'s are independent.

(This would then imply that $N$ and $M$ are independent, and hence $N = 0$, for $M$ is the whole module.)

However, I am having trouble proving this. (I know that this *can* be proven because while surfing, I came across an [uncannily similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4342709/673223) in Dummit and Foote.)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is false.  For instance, let $X$ be any nonzero module and let $M$ be an infinite direct sum of copies of $X$.  If $N$ is one of the direct summands of $M$, then $M\cong M\oplus N$ (since if you remove one of the infinitely many copies of $X$ you still have the same number of them), but $N\neq 0$.

The correct statement is that if $M$ is the *internal* direct sum of $M$ and $N$, then $N=0$.  That is, if the specific map $M\oplus N\to M$ given by $(m,n)\mapsto m+n$ is an isomorphism, then $N=0$.

Comment: Did you mean "...if you remove *finitely* many copies of $X$..."?

Comment: Oops, somehow the words got jumbled up in my head.

Comment: So the exercise of Dummit and Foote that I linked in my post is wrong. Correct? The equivalence (i)$\Leftrightarrow$(iv) therein is exactly what I asked.

Comment: That exercise should probably read: (i) the natural map $\bigoplus_iN_i\to M$ is injective. Otherwise you get the same kind of counterexample: vector space $M$ with basis $e_i$ for $i\geq1$. $N_j=\langle e_{j+1}\rangle$ for $j\geq0$. Then the sum of the $N_j$ is $M$, which is iso to the coproduct of the $N_j$, but the natural map is not an iso.